# Hi, can somebody help me with this loop

Tags: c

Sorry for this question, but I've got no where else to go, and it's getting to me that I cant find a solution. I'm quite good with the programming language Pascal, so this C language seems very familiar to me, but adding an if function which changes the whole structure of a while loop is too complicated for me. Please any help is appreciated.

> The array variable consists of a sequence of ten numbers. Inside the while loop, you must write two if conditions, which change the flow of the loop in the following manner (without changing the printf command):
>
> - If the current number which is about to be printed is less than 5, don't print it.
> - If the current number which is about to be printed is greater than 10, don't print it and stop the loop.
>     Notice that if you do not advance the iterator variable i and use the continue derivative, you will get stuck in an infinite loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int array[] = {1, 7, 4, 5, 9, 3, 5, 11, 6, 3, 4};
    int i = 0;

    while (i < 10)
    {
        /* your code goes here */

        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the Java, C++, and Pascal tags?

Comment: Are you familiar with `continue` and `break`?

Comment: If you're familiar with C, surely you're familiar with `if` and `break`?

Comment: Skeptical on the "good" claim.

Comment: The language you're using is C, so don't add tags that don't apply. Pascal and Java are totally not applicable, and C != C++ (they're not the same thing). I see no effort to put an `if` anywhere yourself in the code you posted. What have you at least tried that isn't working? If you've been "stuck for 4 hours" you should at least have one attempt you can post; please [edit] your question and include it. We're not really a "Here's my starting code. Please finish my homework for me. Thanks." kind of site.

Comment: @BrianRoach: Me, too. Pascal has `if`, `break`, and `continue`, and being "quite good in Pascal" there should be some familiarity with them, I'd think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's testing your understanding of C flow control. What you're looking for is something like:

```
if (array[i] < 5) {i++; continue; }  // increment, go back to while
if (array[i] > 10) break;            // leave while
```

Answer (score 1):

You really want to use `break` and `if` statements.  You will need to know these concepts to be **good** with any language.

```
if (array[i] > 10)
        break;
if (array[i] >= 5)
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
```

Comment: The second if should be `if (array[i] < 5) { i++; continue; }`

Comment: I don't think you need that @ctn. Unless I'm misreading his question.  Sounds like if its <= 5, do nothing, 5 through 10 print, >10 break.  This should be fine.

Comment: Yes, it's not very exactly formulated. One might argue that by including the printf statement in the if you're "changing the printf command". The requirements are obviously intended to teach the student about `continue` and `break`.

Comment: You also have an off-by-one error: the condition in the second if should be `array[i] >= 5`.

Comment: @ctn fixed the off by one error.  I'll leave this solution as it answers the question and I'm not going to guess about the intentions of the assignment (plus I don't like having code with multiple places that update the iterating variable)

Comment: I agree with not updating the iterating variable. The while really should be a for.